# Is diode with forward voltage ~0.15v faulty?

Tags: voltage, diodes, testing, specifications

I tested a diode model SB360 PFS which it showed about 0.15 forward voltage. The reverse voltage is zero. 
[image]
Looking the diode specification I read that Vf is 0.49v to 0.68v. So my question is if this diode is faulty.

Comment: Zero, or out of range (0 to the left on the multimeter display.)

Comment: Assuming you are testing the diode correctly, I am going out on a limb and say that the diode is possibly shorted, which would be a typical fail mode if it is overloaded by sustained over-voltage or over-current.

Comment: @JRE I did not understand your comment. Are you referencing to the reverse voltage ? If yes then it is zero.

Comment: Test it in both directions. If you get the same reading then it is shorted.

Comment: @Transistor please read the question. Diode is typically works as it supposed to work which means no reverse voltage but forward voltage is diverging from the typical 0.4v to 0.6v

Comment: If it shows voltage in one direction but not the other then it isn't shorted.  If it were shorted, it would read zero volts in both directions.  Multimeters show a 0 in the left most digit to indicate out of range.  That's why I asked where the zero is.

Comment: Yes.  That is "out of range."  Really zero would have like 0.0 to the right of the display.

Comment: OL means over limit or more than 2V @ 0.1mA or 20k or whatever CC is used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming by "0" you actually mean "overrange", no that's quite normal (Edit: Yes, .OL stands for over-range). You have a fat 3A Schottky diode, and at 25°C the forward voltage at 10mA is typically around 270mV according to the [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88719/sb320.pdf).

Most multimeters put only about 0.5~1mA through the diode junction, so 150mV at that test current is plausible.

[image]

Note that the higher voltage rated diodes such as the SB360 have more forward drop than the lower-rated ones.

Comment: So you mean that the diode is not faulty right ?

Comment: Almost surely not.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not faulty.  If it showing different values depending on which way you connect it, then it is still acting as a diode

[Page 2 of the datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds23023.pdf) has a chart of forward voltage vs. forward current.

If your meter supplies less than 100mA, then the forward voltage will be below 0.2V - that's the bottom of the chart.

So, your measured 0.15V fits in.  A typical multimeter won't push anything like 100mA through the diode test function.

If your multimeter is showing a 0 on the left of the display that means "out of range."  The voltage required to make the diode conduct in reverse bias is more than the multimeter can supply.

Comment: Other diodes I tested my multimeter showed about 0.486v so that means that multimeter is able to supply more current than 100mA